# Specifying SSH port with Chef, knife bootstrap

Tags: chef, knife

Per Chef's [documentation](https://docs.getchef.com/knife_bootstrap.html), the -p (or --ssh-port) flag should allow me to specify an SSH port, however, the following:

```
knife bootstrap host.com -x user -P password --ssh-port 5846 -N nodename --sudo
```

returns:

```
-bash: --ssh-port: command not found
```

before attempting to connect to port 22. The same is true of "-p". Has anyone come across this, or perhaps caught what I might be doing wrong?

I am running Chef 11.14.6:

```
$ knife -v
Chef: 11.14.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the password contains special characters, like `;` it might trick the shell into believing the command has ended and a new one started. Try to put the password in quotes, or even better, don't put it into the command but let the system ask for it.

Comment: I didn't think of that; the password used an ampersand, it turned out.